# Pinterest layout style is not working in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to use the code from this example at Css Desk (http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) in order to have Pinterest style layout. The code is working fine in Google Chrom, but it does not work in mozilla Firefox. It is displayed as one column. What should I change in the code to make it work?
Css Code

```
html, body{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

#columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: auto;
}

.pin {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 2px solid #FAFAFA;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    margin: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
    opacity: 0.85;

    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your css from this :

```
#columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

to this :

```
#columns {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Remove the auto property for column-fill only for Firefox